# Code issue related to import in talend 7.3.1 jobs

Tags: talend

Recently we have installed talend 7.3.1 in our virtual machine. There is a git repository which stores all of our jobs. while opening some jobs , I get `The import cannot be resolved` error in the code tab of the talend job. When I hover over the under lined error message , I get an option to fix the project setup which when selected performs a background operation and the error gets resolved.

[image]

[image]

There are many jobs with this issue and I am looking for a solution which fixes the issue in all jobs in one shot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have force fully re-synchronized poms and applied the change as per the below screen shot and the issue got resolved.

[image]